# On finite-dimensional approximations of spaces of bounded holomorphic functions outside a bounded domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$. In the applications I have in mind, $\Omega$ is the region inside a polygon (which may or may not be convex). I am interested in the region **outside** $\Omega$. More specifically, let

$\Omega_e = \hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \bar{\Omega}$

(the subscript "e" is for exterior) where $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$ is the Riemann sphere and $\bar{\Omega}$ is the closure of $\Omega$.

I am interested in the vector space

$B = \{ f: \Omega_e \to \mathbb{C}; \text{ $f$ is bounded holomorphic and $f$ extends continuously to $\bar{\Omega}_e$} \}$.

For numerical applications, I would like to "approximate" the space $B$ by a finite-dimensional subspace. The Schwarz-Christoffel mapping $\phi$ maps the unit disk $D$ onto $\Omega_e$ biholomorphically, and extends to a continuous map from $\bar{D}$ to $\bar{\Omega}_e$ which is a homeomorphism.

I have considered the finite-dimensional subspace of $B$ consisting of polynomials in $\phi^{-1}(z)$ of bounded degree, as a finite-dimensional "approximation" of $B$.

This gave good numerical results, for the problem in magnetostatics I was working on with my collaborator, but it has limitations, because computing inverse Schwarz-Christoffel mappings is a hassle.

I would like to find other finite-dimensional approximations of $B$ please.

Here are some issues one may face. If one just considers say polynomials in $1/z$, assuming that $0 \in \Omega$, then the choice of $z=0$ as a preferred pole is not justified for polygonal regions. This is what prompted us to use (inverse) Schwarz-Christoffel mappings, which is highly sensitive to the shape of the polygon. Indeed, the problem we would like to solve, is some matching problem on the boundary of the polygon (meaning on the boundary of $\Omega$).

I hope I have explained the approximation problem sufficiently well. I tried to avoid discussing the full matching problem for brevity. This is though an interesting problem on its own (in my opinion).

Comment: If $F$ is holomorphic on the unit disk and continuous on $|z|\le 1$ then its approximation is given by the $k=k_r$-th Taylor polynomial of $F(rz)$. Since  $\sup_{|z|\le r} |F'(z)|\le 2(1-r)^{-2} \|F\|_\infty$ there is a formula for $r,k_r$ in term of $\|F\|_\infty$ and the desired $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you @reuns once again for your valuable input. What if the domain was the interior of a polygonal region, say a rectangular region for instance? And what if the domain was the exterior of a polygonal region (with a point at infinity)? I know that one approach is to use a Riemann mapping, or in this case, a Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, to reduce the domain to the unit disk. Is there a more direct way though, which avoids using such mappings please?